# Dynamically update email's body in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook

When someone requests access to a SharePoint website, an email is sent to multiple people to ask them to approve the request. I noticed that if I open the email after someone has approved, the email content is updated to show that the request has been approved and by who.

Actually when I open the email, I can see the body that swaps to display the new information!

I tried to inspect the body (using Web Outlook) to understand how Microsoft does that, but I cannot figure it out. And when I open the message in Desktop Outlook, a right-click doesn't work so I cannot look at "View Source".

Any ideas?